# How to add to the visual studio context menu a new command option?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using visual studio community 2022
What have I tried so far is that.

In the visual studio menu, I selected Extensions > Customize Menu... > Commands > Context Menu > Other Context Menus | Selection

now I see the regular context menu commands options when doing right mouse button click on a control in the visual studio:

[image: context menu]

then I click on the right on Add New Menu and then clicked on the right on Modify Selection and then gave it a name Test and marked as Begin a Group and clicked OK button.

[image: context menu]

now when I'm making mouse right click in the designer on a control, I can see the new Test command:

[image: new command added]

the problem is that the new command you can see the Test at the bottom is grayed out disabled and I can't find how to make it enabled. second problem is that it has an arrow on the right like there is a sub command option for the Test but there isn't.

1. How to enable the new command ?
2. How to remove that arrow that show that there is a sub menu command?

Comment: Instead of "Add New Menu" try "Add Command...".